# Mouseover on Covered DIV

Tags: jquery, css

I've got a `div` with an image in it that is covering a bunch of other `div`s.  Something like this:

```
<div style='width:100%;height:100%'><img src='someImage.png'></div>
<div id='covered'>I'm covered by the div above me, but still visible</div>
```

I want to define a jQuery event handler like this:

```
$('#covered').live('mouseover',function(){ do stuff });
```

But the `mouseover` event isn't working because of the `div` that is covering it.  Is there any way to get this to work?

(Notes... the `div` covering it does have a higher z-index because it needs to always be layered on top.  And I'm using "live" because `#covered` get generated dynamically.)

Comment: If you can use jQuery 1.7, look into the .on() .off() methods. live() should no longer be used if at all possible. Other than that, if the underlying elements are known you could populate an old school map and invoke functionality that way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the overlay is the same dimensions as the `#covered` element then you can just bind to the `mouseover` event for the overlay:

```
$(document).delegate('#overlay', 'mouseover', function () { /*run code for `#covered` element*/ });
```

### Update

If the overlay is covering the whole page then you can check the `mousemove` event to see if the cursor has been moved over the `#covered` element:

```
var coveredOffset = $('#covered').offset(),
    coveredWidth  = $('#covered').width(),
    coveredHeight = $('#covered').height();
$('#overlay')​.on('mousemove', function (event) {
    if (event.pageX > coveredOffset.left && event.pageX < (coveredOffset.left + coveredWidth) && event.pageY > coveredOffset.top && event.pageY < (coveredOffset.top + coveredHeight)) {
        console.log('You are mouse-overing #covered');
    }
});​​​​
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/WjRNv/1/ (watch your console to see the log when you mouse-over the `#covered` element)

Comment: Damn, it said a new answer was posted but I didn't mind to show it. :P This general idea of coordinates and all that really amuses me, especially in cases like these. Good work!

Comment: Sorry... the overlay is way larger than the covered div.  Thanks for teaching me about "delegate", though!

Comment: @StevenJenkins This method will work in any-case. You just have to know the relative position of the `#covered` element to the `#overlay` element. And yeah, `.delegate()` is preferred over `.live()` and if you are using jQuery 1.7+ then `.on()` is the preferred method (it handles `.bind()`, `.live()`, and `.delegate()` now). If you want answers that work out-of-the-box then you should create a JSFiddle of your layout so people can give you answers that will work out-of-the-box.

Answer (score 3):

An option is to use [`pointer-events: none`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events). Take into account that it does not work in IE versions lower than 9 and is buggy in IE9 in some cases.

But it would probably be better to revise your styling approach. If the covering `DIV` is transparent, it could likely be under elements that are currently under it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#covered').live('mouseenter',function(){ do stuff });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#covered').mousenter(function(){do stuff}).mouseleave(function(){do so more stuff});
```

OR if the problem is the covering div, you may want to use css to place that image there. With css 3, you can have multiple backgrounds, and they work in a Photoshop layer kinda of way. By doing that, everything will look the same but your js will work perfectly.

Comment: The div that's being covered contains a bunch of stuff and unfortunately isn't just an image.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something different and check the x/y values of the mouse position against the left/top offset of the `div` you want to detect the event on.

```
var topOffset = $("#cover").offset().top,
    leftOffset = $("#cover").offset().left,
    bottomOffset = topOffset + $("#cover").height(),
    rightOffset = leftOffset + $("#cover").width();
$("body").on("mousemove", function(e){
    var mouseX = e.pageX,
        mouseY = e.pageY;
    if(pageX > leftOffset && pageX < rightOffset && pageY > topOffset && pageY < bottomOffset){
        // mouse is within boundaries
    } else {
        // mouse is not within boundaries
    }
});
```

Of course, this becomes problematic when you have padding, margins, etc. And it's a little hard to maintain but it makes perfect sense.